# Boost compilation error on Mac using PCL

Tags: macos, boost, point-cloud-library

I have installed PCL using homebrew on my MacBook. I also have some code which I want to compile for which I have created a CMakeLists.txt file. However, I get some error concerning the boost library.

I get the error:

`/usr/local/include/boost/random/detail/polynomial.hpp:267:13: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'sqr'; did you mean 'sqrt'?
            sqr(out, n);`

When I look in the file polynomial.hpp I can see the following functions:

```
    static digit_t sqr(digit_t val) {
    const std::size_t bits = std::numeric_limits<digit_t>::digits;
    digit_t mask = (digit_t(1) << bits/2) - 1;
    for(std::size_t i = bits; i > 1; i /= 2) {
        val = ((val & ~mask) << i/2) | (val & mask);
        mask = mask & (mask >> i/4);
        mask = mask | (mask << i/2);
    }
    return val;
}

static void sqr(digit_t * val, std::size_t size)
{
    const std::size_t bits = std::numeric_limits<digit_t>::digits;
    digit_t mask = (digit_t(1) << bits/2) - 1;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        digit_t x = val[size - i - 1];
        val[(size - i - 1) * 2] = sqr(x & mask);
        val[(size - i - 1) * 2 + 1] = sqr(x >> bits/2);
    }
}
```

which are declared above the function call which causes the problem.

Since the functions seem to exist and it is the code from the Boost library which causes the problem I am bit unsure how to proceed.

I have not had those problems on Linux, though that was for PCL 1.7 and this is PCL 1.8.

/ Erik

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here (Ubuntu 16.04, PCL 1.8). The error is

```
/usr/include/boost/random/detail/polynomial.hpp:190: error: macro "sqr" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 static void sqr(digit_t * val, std::size_t size)
                                                ^
```

Think it is related.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the sqr to (sqr) in polynomial.hpp. Maybe this is caused by macro in Linux or Mac.